# Jquery/Javascript - Detecting a click outside an element fails on IE when clicking an SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

As in numerous versions of answers I saw online, they all work on chrome/firefox but not on IE when clicking on an svg, for example this snippet:

```
$(document).on("click",(e) => {
    this._handleDocumentClick(e);
});

_handleDocumentClick(e) { 
    let container = $(".myClass");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
        alert('clicked outside');
    }
}
```

On IE this fails to work if you click on an SVG(probably on an image as well), Where the svg is inside my element and it still thinks its outside!

This is the element(and its length) shown when i print e.target:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: i'm not sure if `has` is the right function to go with.. is `e.target` really a string in IE or maybe an element?

Comment: @Alex has works great on chrome/firefox, there is another option with for loop, which acts exactly the same e.target is an element

Comment: ive understood that :) but this doesnt answer my question. also, is ie supporting your syntax (es6?)?

Comment: Try vanilla js: `if (!document.querySelector('.myClass').contains(e.target)' { alert(''clicked outside")}`

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a slightly different approach, checking to see if the target element is a child of the container using jQuery’s `.closest()` method:

```
var $container = $('.target');

$('body').on('click', function(evt) {
  var $target = $(evt.target);

  if ( $target.closest($container).length ) { 
    console.log('❌ click inside');
  }
  else {
    console.log('✅ click outside');
  }

});
```

Here’s a demo, tested in IE9+
http://jsbin.com/qoqume/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: So i tried your example, and it still fails, the reason is i think, that because i am using an svg as : <svg> <use> </use></svg> and the USE object is outside the scope.

Comment: Found the answer, in ie you should us e.target.correspondingUseElement : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff971929(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The answer was the correspondingUseElement property:

In ie only:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff971929(v=vs.85).aspx

Instead of `e.target`, you should use `e.target.correspondingUseElement` in case `e.target.correspondingUseElement !== 'undefined'`